# How to pull all Mercurial bookmarks, but only rebase if the current bookmark has changed?

Tags: mercurial, rebase, bookmarks, pull

With Mercurial, I want to pull *all* bookmarks from my remote repository and rebase the *local* commits of my *current* bookmark onto possibly new *remote* commits of my *current* bookmark.

`hg pull --rebase` will pull *all* bookmarks, however *usually* fails to perform the correct rebase -- most likely it will try to rebase my local commits onto a different, completely unrelated bookmark for which new remote commits had been pulled.

`hg pull -B <bookmark> --rebase` will *only* pull my *current* bookmark, but hence get the rebase right.

Which (sequence of) command(s) is necessary to achieve my goal?

Comment: You are poisoned by Git. You have to throw off an illness and find own Mercurial-way, maybe - not with bookmarks for collaboration, but with another way

Answer (score 1):

I think, you can to see at [hgremotenames extension](https://bitbucket.org/seanfarley/hgremotenames), because it provides more Gitish-way of handling local+remote bookmarks, than default Mercurial style

Comment: Thanks, that looks promising for a Git-poisoned user :)

Comment: @mstrap - but I still recommend to think about old good named branches with, maybe, [remotebranches](https://bitbucket.org/durin42/hg-remotebranches) (parent of remotenames) - added by it bookmarks allow easy differentiation between local and remote trees